# session variable changing when it shouldn't

Tags: php, session-variables

When i receive a request from site:

```
  public function getSiteToken() {
    session_start();
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/api/v3/') !== 0) {
      $_SESSION['siteToken'] = md5(CURRENT_URL.time());
    }
    return $_SESSION['siteToken'];
  }
```

And when i receive from site to the API:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SITE_TOKEN']) && isset($_SESSION['siteToken'])) {
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SITE_TOKEN'] == $_SESSION['siteToken']) return true;
}
```

This works perfectly when i test in POSTMAN. But in the chrome, the second code returns FALSE. Why???

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` for the latter code?  When you debug, what are the runtime values of the various things being checked in these `if` conditions?  What is the request sent to the server?  Which specific part of the `if` conditions isn't producing the expected value?